# Serializing encrypted Class properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, serialization

I'm writing a class that stores email account information. Some of the properties like email address, account password and the server names are stored in encrypted form in Private variables.

The Property Setter encrypts the data and the Getter decrypts it.

Yes I know that storing an encryption key within the software is inherently insecure, but that code will be changed later when I can figure out an alternative. Probably using a key entered by the user or a password that will be used to generate the correct key. At the moment though, the program is for personal use.

When I try to serialize the encrypted information, the information is sent to the xml file in plain text because the information is accessed using the Property Getter which decrypts the data of course.

I don't particularly want to have to expose an extra encrypted property and mark the unencrypted one to be ignored by the serializer - it seems inelegant and possibly less secure.

I could of course do the de/encryption in the main program before it is passed to the property setter, but I wonder if this could be done within the class to keep things neater if I want to reuse the 'EmailAccount' class.

Also I would prefer for the time being at least to have the xml file in plain text so that I can make sure that the en/decryption is working. I realize that I can encrypt the entire file, but that is for later.

Below is a reduced version of the 'EmailAccount' class ..

```
Public Class EmailAccount

    Public Enum UseSSL
        Yes
        No
    End Enum

    Dim _imapPwd As String
    Dim _smtpPwd As String
    Dim _user As String
    Dim _imapServer As String
    Dim _smtpServer As String
    Dim _usessl As UseSSL
    Dim _imapPort As Integer
    Dim _smtpPort As Integer

    Public Property User As String
        Set(value As String)
            _user = Encrypt(value)
        End Set
        Get
            Return Decrypt(_user)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property ImapPassword As String
        Set(value As String)
            _imapPwd = Encrypt(value)
        End Set
        Get
            Return Decrypt(_imapPwd)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property ImapServer As String
        Set(value As String)
            _imapServer = Encrypt(value)
        End Set
        Get
            Return Decrypt(_imapServer)
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub New()
        User = "noemailset@nowhere.com"
        ImapPassword = "nopasswordfddfsg"
        ImapServer = "no.imap.server"
        SmtpPassword = "nopasswordsdfgdf"
        SmtpServer = "no.smtp.server"
        ImapPort = -1
        SmtpPort = -1
        SslState = UseSSL.Yes
    End Sub

    Private Function Encrypt(clearText As String) As String
        Dim EncryptionKey As String = "crypto key goes here"
        Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
        Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
            Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D,
             &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65,
             &H76})
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                    cs.Close()
                End Using
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
        Return clearText
    End Function

    Private Function Decrypt(cipherText As String) As String
        Dim EncryptionKey As String = "crypto key goes here"
        Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)
        Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
            Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D,
             &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65,
             &H76})
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length)
                    cs.Close()
                End Using
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
        Return cipherText
    End Function


End Class
```

In my main form I have the procedure below to serialize the data.

```
''' <summary>
''' Convert a class state into XML
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">The type of object</typeparam>
''' <param name="obj">The object to serilize</param>
''' <param name="FilePath">The path to the XML</param>
Public Shared Sub Serialize(Of T)(ByVal obj As T, Filepath As String)
    Dim XmlBuddy As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
    Dim MySettings As New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings()
    MySettings.Indent = True
    MySettings.CloseOutput = True
    Dim MyWriter As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(Filepath, MySettings)
    XmlBuddy.Serialize(MyWriter, obj)
    MyWriter.Flush()
    MyWriter.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure.  The output from the encryption sub is a string,  so I would assume not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the same thing you are doing in your crypto and use a `CryptoStream` with the serializer stream.  This uses the `BinaryFormatter`:

```vb
Private Sub SaveEmails(data As List(Of EmailAccount), password As String,
                   Filepath As String)
    ' ToDo: further hashing, maybe
    Dim key As Byte() = GetPasswordHash(passW, 32, 62700)
    Dim iv(15) As Byte
    Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(iv)
    End Using

    ' ToDo: Try/Catch
    If File.Exists(Filepath) Then File.Delete(Filepath)

    Using rij = Rijndael.Create()
        rij.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126

        Using cryptor As ICryptoTransform = rij.CreateEncryptor(key, iv),
            fs As New FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)
            ' write the iv to bare stream
            fs.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length)

            Using cs = New CryptoStream(fs, cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Dim bf = New BinaryFormatter
                bf.Serialize(cs, data)
                ' may not be needed - doesnt hurt
                cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function LoadEmails(passW As String, 
                        Filepath As String) As List(Of EmailAccount)
    Dim iv(15) As Byte
    Dim key As Byte() = GetPasswordHash(passW, 32, 62700)

    Dim emails As List(Of EmailAccount)

    Using rijAlg = Rijndael.Create()
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126

        ' to do: check if exists
        Using fs As New FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Open)
            ' read the IV first
            fs.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length)
            ' USING encryptor AND CryptoStream
            Using encryptor As ICryptoTransform = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
                cs As New CryptoStream(fs, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
                emails = CType(bf.Deserialize(cs), List(Of EmailAccount))
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return emails
End Function

Private Function GetPasswordHash(pw As String, count As Int32, iter As Int32) As Byte()
    Dim salt As Byte() = {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D,
                          &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76}

    Using pbkdf As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pw, salt,
                                          iter)
        Return pbkdf.GetBytes(count)
    End Using
End Function
```

One difference is that a random IV is used and it is written to and read from the base stream so that a new one can be used each time you save the file and you do not have to save it anywhere.  These could be shared methods of a Crypto class to create the `CryptoStream` so that code can be worked on separately.

The password is also hashed a little differently.  That hasher is separate so if you change the iterations or method, the encryptor and decryptor dont end up using a different method.

Usage, Testing:

```vb
Dim EmailAccts As New List(Of EmailAccount)
EmailAccts.Add(New EmailAccount With {.User = "Ziggy@ziggysplace.net", .SMTPPass = "secret!pass",
                                      .UseSSL = True, .SMTPServer = "yadayada", .SMTPPort = -42})
EmailAccts.Add(New EmailAccount With {.User = "david@somewhere.com", .SMTPPass = "$tack!overflow$",
                                      .UseSSL = False, .SMTPServer = "blahblah", .SMTPPort = 314})

Dim password As String = "AWeak!pa$$WorD!"

SaveEmails(EmailAccts, password, "C:\Temp\secretemails.bin")
Dim newEmails = LoadEmails(password, "C:\Temp\secretemails.bin")

' is everyone ok?
For Each email In newEmails
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  ... {1}", email.User, email.SMTPPass)
Next
```

Mine was just a simple class of auto properties since that crypto isnt being used.  Everyone survived:

> Ziggy@ziggysplace.net  ... secret!pass
>   david@somewhere.com  ... $tack!overflow$

Comment: Looks like I have a lot to learn about encryption etc. Many thanks. All hail Plutonix!

Comment: You can also use a random number for the number of time to iterate the PW hash and save that to the base stream as well.  Wither it is worth the bother depends on what you are protecting against.  Please upvote if it helped.